# Algorithm/Heuristic for grouping chat message histories by 'conversation'/implicit sessions from time stamps?

Tags: algorithm, heuristics

The problem: I have a series of chat messages -- between two users -- with time stamps.  I could present, say, an entire day's worth of chat messages at once.  During the entire day, however, there were multiple, discrete conversations/sessions...and it would be more useful to the user to see these divided up as opposed to all of the days as one continuous stream.

Is there an algorithm or heuristic that can 'deduce' implicit session/conversation starts/breaks from time stamps?  Besides an arbitrary 'if the gap is more than x minutes, it's a separate session'.  And if that is the only case, how is this interval determined?  In any case, I'd like to avoid this.

For example, there are...fifty messages that get sent between 2:00 and 3:00, and then a break, and then twenty messages sent between 4:00 and 5:00.  There would be a break inserted between there...but how would the break be determined?

I'm sure that there is already literature on this subject, but I just don't know what to search for.

I was playing around with things like edge detection algorithms and gradient-based approaches for a while.

(see comments for more clarification)

Comment: I don't think you can do it based on time, because online chats are often a bit disjointed.  Someone might ask a question or something, and the other person is busy, or part way through, they get sidetracked by a "Real" person, telephone, or even another chat session

Comment: perhaps, and I'm not sure how this would work out, you could break it up by questions and that chat that follows a question

Comment: @Keith I would be interested in a "good enough" algorithm for the less than ideal case.  Edge detection algorithms, for example, aren't perfect -- they miss edges sometimes and add phantom edges.  But they're good enough for their job.

Comment: And for what it's worth, an implementation that breaks sessions between people leaving for the phone for a while is, I think, good enough for this need.  The only thing I really want to is to divide a day's worth of messages into a more comprehensible and human-readable presentation

Comment: Read about clustering algorithms. I think you could use DBSCAN, though there may exist something simpler since you’re essentially clustering points on a line.

Comment: @Artyom As far as I know, DBSCAN in one dimension is exactly the same thing as setting an arbitrary threshold time where you cut-off sessions/conversations.  But I will look into other clustering algorithms to see if one offers something special thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT (Better idea):**

You can view each message as being of two types:

1. A continuation of a previous conversation
2. A brand new conversation

You can model these two types of messages as independent [Poisson processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process), where the time difference between adjacent messages is an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

You can then empirically determine the exponential parameters for these two types of messages by hand (wouldn't be too hard to do given some initial data). Now you have a model for these two events.

Finally when a new message comes along, you can calculate the probability of the message being of type 1 or type 2. If type 2, then you have a new conversation.

**Clarification:**

The probability of the message being a new conversation, given that the delay is some time `T`.

```
P(new conversation | delay=T) = P(new conversation AND delay=T)/P(delay=T)
```

Using Bayes' Rule:

```
= P(delay=T | new conversation)*P(new conversation)/P(delay=T)
```

The same calculation goes for `P(old conversation | delay=T)`.

`P(delay=T | new conversation)` comes from the model. `P(new conversation)` is easily calculable from the data used to generate your model. `P(delay=T)` you don't need to calculate at all since all you want to do is compare the two probabilities.

---

The difference in timestamps between adjacent messages depends on the type of conversation and the people participating. Thus you'll want an algorithm that takes into account local characteristics, as opposed to a global threshold parameter.

My proposition would be as follows:

1. Get the time difference between the last 10 adjacent messages.
2. Compute the mean (or median)
3. If the delay until the next message is more than 30 times the the mean, it's a new conversation.

Of course, I came up with these numbers on the spot. They would have to be tuned to fit your purpose.

Comment: The proposition in your edit is appealing.  I'm not too familiar with the maths of it though; how would I determine the probability of a message being either type?

Comment: You first determine the probability distribution for each type using exponential regression. Once you have the distribution, you can calculate the probability by plugging it into the density function.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  Each type of event occurs at a given frequency...so at every point in time, there's a probability of it happening at x duration after the last is determined by the distribution.  A probability that it's "due", per se.  And when how much a Type 2 is "due" exceeds how much a Type 1 is "due", it's probably a Type 2?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Let me edit my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: After thinking about it and starting on the implementation, I just realized...isn't this basically just a method of finding the parameter for a fixed cut-off delay?  The respective probabilities are only based on T and fixed constants.  So really, the T where the two are equal is the fixed cut off for each conversation, right?

Comment: @JustinL. Oh I suppose that's true... At least it provides a more scientific way of determining the cutoff parameter. Plus you can automate this process if you so desire.